# Facebook PHP API constructor - is local variable ignored for a reason?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Caveat : I am not a PHP guru by any stretch - hopefully someone can explain what this code is doing - why is he applying something to a local variable ($state) and then ignoring it?  This code is in the 3.1.1 php sdk and I noticed it when debugging an issue with js sdk and php interactions during an authResponse trigger.

```
  public function __construct($config) {
    $this->setAppId($config['appId']);
    $this->setApiSecret($config['secret']);
    if (isset($config['fileUpload'])) {
      $this->setFileUploadSupport($config['fileUpload']);
    }

    $state = $this->getPersistentData('state');
    if (!empty($state)) {
      $this->state = $this->getPersistentData('state');
    }
  }
```

Is it as simple as he meant to use $this->state = $state?

Comment: If people dont answer or use that, its hard. In the few questions I have asked most are answered or commented on. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an oversight on the programmers side I think. He could and should have assigned $state to $this->state.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't being ignored. On the next line, it's used as a parameter for `empty`.

Parameters to `empty` must be variables ([see manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)), which is why it's being used like that.

However, they could probably have used it in the `$this->state` assignment as well. Why they didn't I wouldn't know.

Comment: I assume you don't want to override the `$this->state` with an empty result. So you store the result to be able to use the `empty()` function, and if it is empty you don't want to do anything.

Comment: Well, obviously you dont want to override it with an empty state, the empty check ensures that, its the following assignment that I referred to in the last line of my Q.

Comment: Well they could have used the `$state` variable in the assignment inside the if-block. That's what I was referring to. Now it calls the getter again for no reason.